# Using a scope, how to define the controller in a routes file (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to use a scope in my routes file to get all these requests using the datareq controller

```
scope 'data/request' do
    get 'mine', :to => "datareq#mine"
    get '...', :to => "datareq#something"
    get '...', :to => "datareq#somethingelse"
end
```

Is there a way to get these to all use the datareq controller without having to specify them all the time individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
scope 'data/request', controller: 'datareq' do
  get 'mine', action: :mine
  get '...', action: :something
  get '...', action: :somethingelse
end
```